# How to use grep and cut in script to obtain website URLs from an HTML file

Tags: shell-script, grep, string, cut

I am trying to use grep and cut to extract URLs from an HTML file. The links look like:

```
<a href="http://examplewebsite.com/">
```

Other websites have `.net`, `.gov`, but I assume I could make the cut off point right before `>`. So I know I can use grep and cut somehow to cut off everything before http and after .com, but I have been stuck on it for a while.

Comment: why not match the opening and ending quote of href parameter ? besides , i believe regular expressions are not best fit for html's .

Comment: I want to write a command using specifically grep and cut to do it. I realize there are other ways, but I wanted to know about those.

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to parse HTML with Regular Expressions, since HTML is not a regular language. If you can _guarantee_ that the HTML you're parsing is fairly simple, and the stuff you're trying to extract is predictable you _may_ be able to get away with it. But please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4014959

Comment: [urlextract](https://github.com/lipoja/URLExtract/) was able to parse malformed HTML (lynx gives the `Bad HTML!` error for the page, or a local HTML file in this case.) — from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189929/6404709)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it's generally not a good idea to parse HTML with Regular Expressions, but you can sometimes get away with it if the HTML you're parsing is well-behaved.

In order to only get URLs that are in the `href` attribute of `<a>` elements, I find it easiest to do it in multiple stages. From your comments, it looks like you only want the top level domain, not the full URL. In that case you can use something like this:

```bash
grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' source.html |
grep -Eo 'href="[^\"]+"' | 
grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+'
```

where `source.html` is the file containing the HTML code to parse.

This code will print all top-level URLs that occur as the `href` attribute of any `<a>` elements in each line. The `-i` option to the first `grep` command is to ensure that it will work on both `<a>` and `<A>` elements. I guess you could also give `-i` to the 2nd `grep` to capture upper case `HREF` attributes, OTOH, I'd prefer to ignore such broken HTML. :)

To process the contents of `http://google.com/`

```
wget -qO- http://google.com/ |
grep -Eoi '<a [^>]+>' | 
grep -Eo 'href="[^\"]+"' | 
grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^/"]+'
```

**output**

```
http://www.google.com.au
http://maps.google.com.au
https://play.google.com
http://www.youtube.com
http://news.google.com.au
https://mail.google.com
https://drive.google.com
http://www.google.com.au
http://www.google.com.au
https://accounts.google.com
http://www.google.com.au
https://www.google.com
https://plus.google.com
http://www.google.com.au
```

My output is a little different from the other examples as I get redirected to the Australian Google page.

Comment: @mavavilj: Because the OP only wanted the the top level domain, so  after the `://` we only accept chars before the first `/` or `"`. But if you want to see the full URL, change that command to `grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^"]+`. Another option for that line is `grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^?"]+'` which cuts off query options. However, that variation will still print URLs that are contained within another URL as a query parameter, but they'll be printed on a separate line.

Answer (score 69):

Not sure if you are limited on tools:

But regex might not be the best way to go as mentioned, but here is an example that I put together:

```
cat urls.html | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*" | sort -u
```

- `grep -E` : is the same as egrep
- `grep -o` : only outputs what has been grepped
- `(http|https)` : is an either / or
- `a-z` : is all lower case
- `A-Z` : is all upper case
- `.` : is dot
- `/` : is the slash
- `?` : is ?
- `=` : is equal sign
- `_` : is underscore
- `%` : is percentage sign
- `:` : is colon
- `-` : is dash
- `*`: is repeat the [...] group
- `sort -u` : will sort & remove any duplicates

Output:

```
bob@bob-NE722:~s$  wget -qO- https://stackoverflow.com/ | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" | sort -u
https://stackauth.com
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/svg-icons
https://stackoverflow.com
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertising
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head
https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/help
https://chat.stackoverflow.com
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
...
```

You can also add in `\d` to catch other numeral types.

Comment: [IRI regexes!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/3622940) Use one of them and scare the OP! :)

Comment: @muru ... *shivering* I ... I don't know what to say. Are those even real!?

Answer (score 14):

If your grep supports Perl regexes:

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")'
```

- `(?<=href=")` and `(?=")` are [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) expressions for the `href` attribute. This needs the `-P` option.
- `-o` prints the matching text.

For example:

```
$ curl -sL https://www.google.com | grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=")'
/search?
https://www.google.co.in/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN&tab=w1
https://news.google.co.in/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
...
```

As usual, there's no guarantee that these are valid URIs, or that the HTML you're parsing will be valid.

Answer (score 13):

As a [non-regex alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1045510), use [pup](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup):

```
pup 'a[href] attr{href}' < yourfile.html
```

Will find all `a` elements that have a `href` attribute, then display the value of the `href` attribute.

You can get it from the Releases page in the GitHub, or by compiling it yourself, in which case you'll need Go (a programming language).

The advantage of this solution is that it [doesn't rely on the HTML being properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1045510).

Comment: +1 for `pup`, time to install that....

Comment: You can put them in file as well. `pup 'a.classname[href] attr{href}' < tut.html >links.md`

Answer (score 3):

[I have found a solution here](https://h3manth.com/content/hyperlink-url-extracting-all-links-site) that is IMHO much simpler and potentially faster than what was proposed here. I have adjusted a little bit to support https files. But the TD;TR version is ...

PS: You can replace the site URL with a path to a file and it will work the same way.

```
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "http://www.goggle.com" > links.txt

lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "some-file.html" > links.txt
```

If you just want to see the links instead of placing them in a file, then try this instead ...

```
lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "http://www.google.com"

lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers "some-file.html"
```

The result will look similar to the following ...

```
http://www.google.ca/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
http://maps.google.ca/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8
http://www.youtube.com/?gl=CA&tab=w1
http://news.google.ca/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
https://www.google.ca/intl/en/options/
http://www.google.ca/history/optout?hl=en
...
etc.
```

For my use case, this worked just fine. But beware of the fact that nowadays, people add links like src="//blah.tld" for CDN URI of libraries. I didn't want to see those in the retrieved links.

No need to try to check for href or other sources for links because "lynx -dump" will by default extract all the clickable links from a given page. So the only think you need to do after that is to parse the result of "lynx -dump" using grep to get a cleaner raw version of the same result.

Comment: This is really handy .. if you're using with xargs it's worth adding  | sort | uniq  to trim the duplicate links.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -qO- google.com |
tr \" \\n | grep https\*://
```

...would probably do pretty well. As written, it prints:

```
http://schema.org/WebPage
http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8
http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1
http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/
http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&continue=http://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/project/the-holocaust?utm_source=google&amp;utm_medium=hppromo&amp;utm_campaign=auschwitz_q1&amp;utm_content=desktop
https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550
```

If it is important that you only match links and from among those top-level domains, you can do:

```
wget -qO- google.com |
sed '/\n/P;//!s|<a[^>]*\(https*://[^/"]*\)|\n\1\n|;D'
```

...or something like it - though for some `sed`s you may need to substitute a literal `\n`ewline character for each of the last two `n`s.

As written, the above command prints:

```
http://www.google.com
http://maps.google.com
https://play.google.com
http://www.youtube.com
http://news.google.com
https://mail.google.com
https://drive.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
https://plus.google.com
```

...and for either case *(but probably most usefully with the latter)* you can tack on a `|sort -u` filter to the end to get the list `sort`ed and to drop duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest

```
grep -r http . --color
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<a href="http://examplewebsite.com/">"|sed -r 's:<.*"::g'|sed 's:/">$::g'
```